# Exported blob data different than DB data

Tags: character-encoding, mysql

I'm attempting to export our very large MySQL database (1.6GB  - mostly BLOB) and import into a new server.  I have worked through most of the problems and finally completed the import without any errors.  Using MySQL Query Browser I ran a query on a table with BLOBs of images and saved one to disk (using the save icon in query browser).  When I tried to open the file I received an "invalid image format" error.  Uh oh.

Using query browser I inspected the value on the source database and the new, recently imported database.  The values are different, I think.  It could just be encoding issues or something.  Here is what I see:

Source (valid data) server:

```
FF D8 FF E0    00 10 4A 46    49 46 00 01    01 01 00 60
00 60 00 00    FF DB 00 43    00 08 06 06    07 06 05 08
and so on...
```

New server:

```
C3 BF C3 98    C3 BF C3 A0    00 10 4A 46    49 46 00 01
01 01 00 60    00 60 00 00    C3 BF C3 9B    00 43 00 08
and so on...
```

In this example it appears to my newbie eye that there are 3 bytes of extra data in the front of the data on the "new" server.

I then checked out the sql dump file using [010 editor](http://www.sweetscape.com/010editor/).  I found the line for this particular example and here is what I see:

```
FF D8 FF E0    5C 30 10 4A    46 49 46 5C    30 01 01 01
5C 30 60 5C    30 60 5C 30    5C 30 FF DB    5C 30 43 5C
30 08 06 06    07 06 05 08    and so on...
```

Now I'm way over my head.  I see the pattern, I do notice that the HEX pair 5C 30 appears to be the same as 00 but I don't understand WHY.  At this point I have a source server that is about to be wiped and a new one that I'm afraid has corrupt data imported into it.  I'm hoping this is some kind of encoding issue that can be solved by setting a global variable in MySQL but I really don't know.

I should also mention that when I save the files from the source (working) server and the new (corrupt) server the files size is about 40% larger for the corrupt file.

I checked the character set variables on both servers:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%char%'
```

source server:

```
character_set_client      utf8
character_set_connection  utf8
character_set_database    latin1
character_set_filesystem  binary
character_set_results     utf8
character_set_server      latin1
character_set_system      utf8
```

new server:

```
character_set_client      utf8
character_set_connection  utf8
character_set_database    latin1
character_set_filesystem  binary
character_set_results     utf8
character_set_server      latin1
character_set_system      utf8
```

They are the same.

Comment: FYI 1.6 Gb is just a baby in database terms!

Comment: The hex string `5C 30` is `\0`, so that looks like some strange behaviour either with the editor, or the content of the SQL dump has been manipulated/broken somehow.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The corrupted data from the new database looks like the result of converting the source data from ISO‑8859‑1 to UTF‑8 (e.g. U+00FF — ÿ — is `FF` in the former and `C3 BF` in the latter).

Since BLOBs have no character set, the character encoding is not controlled by server variables; I suspect `mysqldump` is outputting your BLOB data in a UTF-8–encoded file ([which is the default](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_default-character-set)), and it is encoded along the way somehow, through some combination of server settings and options passed to `mysqldump`.

The best solution may be to use the [`--hex-blob`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_hex-blob) option when exporting BLOB fields, which would result in something like:

```
INSERT INTO `table` VALUES (0xFFD8FFE0...);
```